# Show different banner based on user profile

Tags: visualforce, community, force.com-sites, html, images

I have two different banners used on my community site, one for internal users and one for external users. I would like users to see the banner corresponding to their user profile type.  Could I make the image a variable and display it on the VF page using an if statement in the controller or an extension?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it for sure. You don't even need to write any apex code for that. You can use a global visualforce variable `$Profile` for accessing a profile name of the current user. Then render the image based on that information:

The easies example:

```
<img src="/img/{!IF($Profile.Name == 'Profile Name', 'someBanner.jpg', 'defaultBanner.jpg')}" />
```

Usually the pictures are coming from static resources. In that case I would put every image in a outputPanel and render it depending on the profile name:

```
<apex:outputPanel render="{!$Profile.Name == 'ProfileName1'}">
    <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.banners, 'someBanner.jpg')}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```